# jsf search display total results found in a datatable

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I was wondering if you could point me in the right direction,I have a search method and it works fine but I would like to display the total results found,I was wondering how I implement something like that

```
public List<Testpaper> Paper(String q)throws SQLException {
    List<Testpaper> test = new ArrayList<Testpaper>();

    if(ds==null)
    throw new SQLException("Can't get data source");

//get database connection
Connection con = ds.getConnection();

if(con==null)
    throw new SQLException("Can't get database connection");

PreparedStatement ps 
    = con.prepareStatement(
        "select * from test where testname like ? or subject like ?;"); 
    try {
        ps.setString(1, "%" + q + "%");
        ps.setString(2,"%"+ q + "%");
        ResultSet  result =  ps.executeQuery();        
        while (result.next()) {
            Testpaper testpaper = new Testpaper();
            testpaper.setTestname(result.getString("testname"));
            testpaper.setDescription(result.getString("description"));
            testpaper.setDateuploaded(result.getDate("dateuploaded"));
            testpaper.setLink(result.getString("link"));
            testpaper.setYear(result.getString("year"));
            testpaper.setSubject(result.getString("subject"));
            test.add(testpaper);
        }
    } catch(Exception e1) {

    }
    finally{
        try{
            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e2) {            
        }
    }
    return test;
}
```

JSF code

```html
<h:dataTable value="#{search.test}" id="result" var="test"
    rendered="#{not empty search.test}">
    <h:column>
        <a href="#{test.link}" title="Download">
            <h3 style="font-size: medium;font-weight: normal;color: rgb(17, 34, 204);display: block; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; ">
                <h:outputText value="#{test.testname}" />
            </h3>
        </a>
        <h:outputText value="Created by:Ainsley Hanson/Portmore Missionar Prep School"/>
        <p style="line-height: 1.24;direction:rtl;width: 400px;">#{test.description}</p>
        <div >
            <h:outputText value="Test year: #{test.year}"
                style="color:rgb(17, 34, 204);margin-right: 10px;"/>
            <h:outputText value="Date Uploaded: #{test.dateuploaded}"
                style="color:rgb(17, 34,  );margin-right: 10px;">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM.dd.yyyy HH:mm" />
            </h:outputText>                                                                 
            <h:outputText value="Subject :   #{test.subject}"
                style="font-weight:100;color:rgb(17, 34, 204);"/>
        </div>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

I know that it should be displayed outside the datatable but should you get the result from mysql.

Comment: Post what have you tried in both JSF and Java code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSTL [`fn:length()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/fn/length.fn.html) function to get the value of `List#size()` in EL.

```html
<html ... xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">
...
<p>Total results: #{fn:length(search.test)}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the facelets size method instead of using JSTL:

Something like #{myBean.myList.size()}

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EL 2.2, you can simply take advantage of new EL specifications and print results count like this :

```
Results count : #{search.test.size()}
```